# Unable to find large files in Linux using "du -h"

Tags: linux, hadoop

I have a hadoop cluster running out of space recently. I try to clean some logs to get some disk space. I run the command `df -h`, it shows:

```
/dev/sda1        22G   20G  1.9G  92% /
/dev/sda3       1.8T  747G  960G  44% /data/1
/dev/sdb1       1.8T  755G  986G  44% /data/2
/dev/sdc1       1.8T  754G  987G  44% /data/3
/dev/sdd1       1.8T  745G  996G  43% /data/4
```

The HDFS is under the dir `/data` which is fine. But the root dir `/` has little space left. So I used the tool `ncdu` which can calculate rapidly the disk usage of dir, it shows:

```
  2.9TiB [##########] /data
  1.5GiB [          ] /home
800.9MiB [          ] /usr
716.3MiB [          ] /var
349.1MiB [          ] /lib
293.8MiB [          ] /opt
```

There is no large directory. I also tried the command such as `du -a | sort -n -r | head`, still unable to find this invisible dir or file. Does anyone know some other way to find out where the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally find the answer.

**Cause**
I have deleted a large log file but didn't reclaim space in filesystem and it's still taking the disk space. That's why the result of the commands `du -h` and `df -h` does not match.

**Solution**

```
root@linux:# lsof / | grep deleted
java    15393    hdfs    114w    REG    8,1    4463704    655506    /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-hslave.log (deleted)
```

The command `lsof` list the open files. The file was opened when I deleted it. The second column shows the PID of the process which opened this file.

```
root@linux:# cd /proc/15393/fd/
root@linux:# ls -l | grep deleted
l-wx------ 1 hdfs hadoop 64 Jul 25 17:55 114 -> /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-hslave.log (deleted)
root@linux:# > 114
```

Type the file descriptor shows in the previous line (114). Now the space is reclaimed.

Comment: It was easy for me reboot the server and start all over ;). But you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

There could be large files hidden by the `/data` mountpoint, or other mountpoints. For instance if you write a 10G file to `/data/large.bin` and then mount another filesystem atop `/data`, the 10G file will be effectively invisible.

You can see if that's the case by binding `/` to another location:

```
mkdir /tmp/slash
mount --bind / /tmp/slash
```

If you then measure `/tmp/slash`'s usage you'll see what's on the root filesystem only. If `/tmp/slash/data` shows up as full then that means there's hidden data there.

Comment: I did it as you said, but still no large files found nor `/data`

Comment: Basically, the result of `df -h` and `du -h` doesn't match. Besides `/data`, the total of `du` is far smaller than `df`. There are effectively some invisible files cannot be found.